# Passing struct data arguments to threads

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads

I'm confused on how to pass struct arguments to threads in the for loop.

When I try with this approach, I get garbage port values. When I try to change the `struct` to just `astruct argstruct;` without the pointer, the second port overwrites the first one so I get `200` `200` printed.

Also, would I have to `free` the struct in `main`, `Func`, or both?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void* Func(void* pstruct);

typedef struct thread_args{
    int port;
} astruct;

int main()
{
    int peers[2] = {100,200};
    pthread_t threads[2];
    astruct *argstruct[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        argstruct[i] = malloc(sizeof(astruct));
        argstruct[i]->port = peers[i];
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,Func,&argstruct[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void* Func(void* pstruct){
    int port;
    astruct *argstruct = (astruct *)pstruct;
    
    port = argstruct->port;
    printf("port: %d\n", port);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JanezKuhar When you do: `Func` [without parens] it _is_ the _address_ of the function. The `&` doesn't hurt, but using [merely] `Func` is more canonical. It allows `Func` to be a function _pointer_ (e.g.): `void *(*Func)(void *) = otherFunc;` and `Func` can be passed to `pthread_create` (e.g.) `pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, Func, argstruct[i]);` Thus, function addresses and pointers to functions can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I'm confused on how to pass struct arguments to threads in the for loop.*

`argstruct[i]` elements are pointers, you don't need address operator:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, Func, argstruct[i]);
```

Note that you wouldn't need memory allocation for this simple case, you can use a local array:

```
//...
astruct argstruct[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {   
    argstruct[i].port = peers[i];
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, Func, &argstruct[i]);
}
//...
```

---

> *Also, would I have to `free` the struct in main, Func, or both?*

You should free it one time only. The procedure is always the same, you free it when you don't need it anymore, that can be in the the thread routine or in `main`.

In your example, you could very well free the memory after `port = argstruct->port;` as you no longer use it after this assignment:

```
void* Func(void* pstruct){
    int port;
    astruct *argstruct = (astruct *)pstruct;
    
    port = argstruct->port;
    free(argstruct); //<-- here
    printf("port: %d\n", port);
    return 0;
}
```